# Need explain to understand asio REFERENCE_COUNTED example

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, smart-pointers

The sample I'm looking at in full is:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

// A reference-counted non-modifiable buffer class.
class shared_const_buffer
{
public:
  // Construct from a std::string.
  explicit shared_const_buffer(const std::string& data)
    : data_(new std::vector<char>(data.begin(), data.end())),
      buffer_(boost::asio::buffer(*data_))
  {
  }
  // Implement the ConstBufferSequence requirements.
  typedef boost::asio::const_buffer value_type;
  typedef const boost::asio::const_buffer* const_iterator;
  const boost::asio::const_buffer* begin() const { return &buffer_; }
  const boost::asio::const_buffer* end() const { return &buffer_ + 1; }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > data_;
  boost::asio::const_buffer buffer_;
};

class session
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime.
    time_t now = time(0);
    shared_const_buffer buffer(ctime(&now));
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffer,
        boost::bind(&session::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
  }

  void handle_write()
  {
  }

private:
  // The socket used to communicate with the client.
  tcp::socket socket_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<session> session_ptr;

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    session_ptr new_session(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session_ptr new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
    }

    new_session.reset(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: reference_counted <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    using namespace std; // For atoi.
    server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm a java programmer trying to understand how boost asio work, there are some points I need help with. My questions are:

1. In these lines:

   ```
   const boost::asio::const_buffer* begin() const { return &buffer_; }
   const boost::asio::const_buffer* end() const { return &buffer_ + 1; }
   ```

   this `shared_const_buffer` is use to `async_write` later, so I think it should implement some kind of buffer but I don't see any inherit signature. So define `begin()` and `end()` are enough?
2. And in these lines:

   ```
   shared_const_buffer buffer(ctime(&now));
   boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffer, 
                            boost::bind(&session::handle_write, 
                                        shared_from_this()));
   ```

   `share_const_buffer` has `data_` is a shared pointer, but not itself, how is `buffer` valid until `async_write` actually writes the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this `shared_const_buffer` is use to `async_write()` later, so I think it
>   should implement some kind of buffer but I don't see any inherit
>   signature. So define `begin()` and `end()` are enough?

The buffer used by the `shared_const_buffer` class is its `_data` member, a `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> >`. Exposing iterators to the buffer is sufficient for using it with `async_write()`.

> `share_const_buffer` has `data_` is a shared pointer, but not itself, how
>   is buffer valid until `async_write()` actually writes the data?

The `shared_const_buffer` class implements the asio [`ConstBufferSequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) type requirements

```
  // Implement the ConstBufferSequence requirements.
  typedef boost::asio::const_buffer value_type;
  typedef const boost::asio::const_buffer* const_iterator;
  const boost::asio::const_buffer* begin() const { return &buffer_; }
  const boost::asio::const_buffer* end() const { return &buffer_ + 1; }
```

so when invoking `async_write` it is copied, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) explicitly states this:

> **buffers**
>
> One or more buffers containing the data to be written.
>   Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of
>   the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must
>   guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

The underlying data however, is not copied since it is retained in a `shared_ptr`. You can see this can be seen by sprinkling some debugging statements

```
--- reference_counted.cpp   2012-02-19 08:30:32.000000000 -0600
+++ reference_counted_good.cpp  2012-02-19 08:26:27.000000000 -0600
@@ -26,9 +26,7 @@
     : data_(new std::vector<char>(data.begin(), data.end())),
       buffer_(boost::asio::buffer(*data_))
   {
-      std::cout << "shared_const_buffer()" << std::endl;
   }
-  ~shared_const_buffer() { std::cout << "~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: " << data_.use_count() << std::endl; }

   // Implement the ConstBufferSequence requirements.
   typedef boost::asio::const_buffer value_type;
@@ -66,7 +64,6 @@

   void handle_write()
   {
-      std::cout << "handle_write" << std::endl;
   }

 private:
```

and running it

```
Sam-Millers-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow samm$ ./a.out 1234
shared_const_buffer()
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 8
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 7
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 6
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 5
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 4
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 3
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 3
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 2
handle_write
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 2
~shared_const_buffer() buffer use count: 1
```

in another shell

```
Sam-Millers-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow samm$ telnet localhost 1234
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Sun Feb 19 08:22:56 2012
Connection closed by foreign host.
Sam-Millers-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow samm$
```

So the actual buffer remains valid until the last `shared_const_buffer` goes out of scope and runs the descriptor

Comment: okie, in java-world, shared_const_buffer need to implement a kind of buffer so it could be cast to the base type, and call the interface method to obtain the buffer. How dose it work in case of shared_const_buffer in c++ ?

Comment: I've create an other test, c++ dose not require type checking, that's why shared_const_buffer no need to explicit implement an interface.

Comment: @secmask I wouldn't advise approaching a C++ programming project assuming it should behave like Java.